# Bulma - fit image and footer on one browser window without scrolling

Tags: css, bulma

I would like to display the image and footer to always fit the browser window - no scrolling. In order to fit the image should be resized while keeping the ratio. Footer should always be at the bottom and the image fill the rest of the space.
I thought this should be easy to achieve with bulma - but so far i couldn't make it work. Is the hero-layout not the right layout to achieve this with bulma?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="hero" style="height: 100vh">
      <div class='hero-body is-paddingless'>
        <figure class='image'>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x800">
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class='hero-foot'>
        <div class='box'>
          hero-foot
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: facing this same issue. thanks for asking! any luck finding an answer?

Answer (score 2):

First, I dont think many knows what bulma or hero-layout is, but if you want a background to be a picutre and fit the whole screen you should try it with this, this also should make the page be full width without scrolling:

CSS:

```
body, html {
height: 100%;
}

.bg { 
background-image: url("your_background");
height: 100%; 
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

If that doesnt work for you, you can try disabling scrolling:

```
overflow: hidden;
```